# High Elevation Souffle

Tags: high-altitude, souffle

I am making a Blue Cheese Souffle today and because I live in the Mile-Hi city, I am a little concerned about it not working.  Are there any special tips - specifically for Souffle's at high altitude or elevation?

I have tried everything imaginable for my favorite chocolate cake and the only time it did not sink it tasted very bad, so I have learned to live with a sinking cake.  I would like to balance the flavor with the rise, so please include side effects for any suggested tip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Mary,

Everything I see online does indicate that souffles can be problematic at altitude, so you're right to seek advice.

Here's two resources for help:

- Cooking At High Altitude Blog: http://cookingathighaltitude.blogspot.com/2008/11/chocolate-souffle.html
- Pie in the Sky Cookbook: http://www.powells.com/biblio/62-9780060522582-0